# Why is vm_compute faster in definitions than in proofs in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have a `Fixpoint` function `f` and a lemma of the following form:

```
Lemma L: forall x, f x = true -> P x.
```

When I define a variable `a` for which `f a = true`, I can prove `P a` in the following way:

```
Lemma: P a.
Proof. apply L. vm_compute. easy. Qed.
```

However, the evaluation of `f` is much faster (2mn versus 6mn) inside a definition:

```
Definition foo := Eval vm_compute in (f a).
```

Is there a reason for this difference, and is there a way to use it to prove `P a` faster?

PS: just in case, `a` is actually a long list of trees.

Comment: If you rely on such computation-intensive proofs, you may want to try [native_compute](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.native-compute) if it is available on your installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might know that Coq's proof mode is just a wrapper to build proof terms interactively.  During this process, Coq does some preliminary checking to rule out errors, but the real work happens when you hit `Qed`, which causes Coq to type check the resulting term. My guess is that `f a` is being computed *twice*: once for the preliminary checks, and then for the definitive checks.